# FFMPEG undefined reference to `avdevice_register_all'

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm trying to build simple programm using ffmpeg

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
extern "C" {
 #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
 #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
 #include <libavformat/avio.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavutil/time.h>
 }


#include <iostream> 


 int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
 {
   AVCodec *icodec;
  AVFormatContext *ifcx = NULL;
  AVInputFormat *ifmt;
  AVCodecContext *iccx;
   AVStream *ist;
   AVStream *ost;
   AVPacket pkt;
   int i_index;
  int64_t timenow, timestart;
   int got_key_frame = 0;

   AVFormatContext *ofcx;

   const char *sProg = argv[ 0 ];
   const char *sFileInput;
   const char *sFileOutput;
  int64_t bRunTime;

  bRunTime = atoi( argv[ 2 ] ) * 1000000;

   // Initialize library
   av_log_set_level( AV_LOG_DEBUG );
   av_register_all();
   avcodec_register_all(); 
   avformat_network_init();
   avdevice_register_all();
```

And i get these errors

g++ -o rtsp3 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include rtsp3.cpp -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lm -lz -lva -lpthread
/tmp/ccAXDgvi.o: In function `main':
rtsp3.cpp:(.text+0x115): undefined reference to`avdevice_register_all'
/usr/local/lib/libavformat.a(matroskadec.o): In function `matroska_decode_buffer':
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg-git/ffmpeg/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1242: undefined reference to`BZ2_bzDecompressInit'
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg-git/ffmpeg/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1257: undefined reference to `BZ2_bzDecompress'
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg-git/ffmpeg/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1250: undefined reference to`BZ2_bzDecompressEnd'
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg-git/ffmpeg/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1262: undefined reference to `BZ2_bzDecompressEnd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have  git version of ffmpeg and successfully compiled it and make install.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
gcc -o main.o main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs libavformat libavutil`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with libavdevice, e.g. `-lavdevice`

Also, apparently, libbz2, e.g. `-lbz2`

Comment: I made as you suggested but have new errors :/usr/local/lib/libavdevice.a(alsa-audio-dec.o): In function `audio_read_packet':
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg-git/ffmpeg/libavdevice/alsa-audio-dec.c:108: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_readi'
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg-git/ffmpeg/libavdevice/alsa-audio-dec.c:125: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_delay'
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg-git/ffmpeg/libavdevice/alsa-audio-dec.c:115: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
/usr/local/lib/libavdevice.a(alsa-audio-dec.o): In function `audio_read_header':
 and so on

Comment: Looks like you need to link with alsa. e.g. `-lasound`

Comment: /usr/local/lib/libavdevice.a(lavfi.o): In function `lavfi_read_packet':
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg-git/ffmpeg/libavdevice/lavfi.c:338: undefined reference to `av_buffersink_get_frame_flags'
/home/user/projects/ffmpeg-git/ffmpeg/libavdevice/lavfi.c:360: undefined reference to `av_buffersink_get_frame_flags'

Comment: There's a pkgconfig file that contains all the right flags to use for your build. You can use pkg-config --libs libavdevice to get a list of all flags to link with libavdevice.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing libbz2-dev

On Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev`

Answer (score 0):

check if you have object files for libav format added in the path. You have added librarians properly in the makefile so problem shouldn't have come.
If you are using ubuntu, check if this is preset
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so

If not, you need to install libavformat-dev

you can install it using "sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev"

I was facing the same issues and it got resolved after this.